# Gradle multi project - sharing source code between projects

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

In a gradle multi project (java), it is possible to share source code so that each project has access to it and compiles against it?

For example, sub projects 'mouse', 'cat', 'dog', containing a single java class in each - `Mouse.java` `Cat.java`, and `Dog.java` respectively. Each of these classes extends `Animal.java`.

A caveat is that when any given sub-project (e.g, 'mouse') is being built, it has some compile time dependencies defined (from maven central) and it requires that `Animal.java` gets compiled **using those some dependencies**. The same goes for the other projects. So, I can't compile and jar up `Animal.java` and then use that jar as a dependency of the 3 projects. Animal must get recompiled together with the source of the dependent project. The result should be mouse.jar, cat.jar, and dog.jar, each in their respective project build dir (as usual) and each also containing their version of Animal.class.

I understand that the example isn't very intuitive (as Animal should be generic enough to be compiled independently). It's the best I could find to simulate the hard to explain scenario I'm trying to solve.

Is that possible to do in Gradle?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this link helps (apparently, as a Gradle noobie, it didn't help me, but it sounds good) https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Thanks @Danielson. I am indeed using common configuration at the parent project of these 3 (in fact there are about 12 sub projects), and that works well. However I don't see a suggestion there on how to share common code and recompile it with different dependencies each time.

Comment: I wish I could help, I tried (but was shown wrong). How do you mean `share`? With others? Then you need to `deploy` it to a general server

Comment: So you'll effectively have 3 different versions of `animal.class`? How does this work at runtime? Which version will your classloader load? Besides the question of how to do this in gradle, what you're doing is a very bad idea, defeating the whole point of abstracting animal.java in the first place.

Comment: @RaGe I agree that it looks bad - but that's just because of the overly simplified example I gave. In reality these are connectors that are loaded via reflection by different class loaders, and it works well and serves the purpose. Don't take the animal example too literally. Think of 'animal' as common logic that all 3 classes use. Currently this common logic is duplicated across all 3 and I'd like to extract it out. If there's a better way to do it other than inheritance that's fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved this with sourceSets. Added the parent project main source set to the sub projects:

e.g, added to `build.gradle` of project 'mouse':

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir project(':animal').sourceSets.main.java
}
```

Comment: How do I exclude a file from `:animal` project?

Comment: Wow, is that all I really have to do to replace MPP with Gradle? Can you explain it more, is there a doc reference I haven't found? I usually just use sourceSets for dependencies. This is groovy not Kotlin correct? Your assigning the main java source dir to another project? Can you have more than one srcDir?

Comment: could you please show how to do this in kotlin dsl aswell?

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for project ':shared' - any idea how to fix it?